# inserting guid as primary key - best practice

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using GUId as Primary Key. Is this a proper way to implement it during insert?

```
    var item = new tbl_A(){
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")    
    };
  _context.tbl_A.Add(item);
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why is there a `ToString`? If `Id` isn't of type `Guid` -- why not?

Comment: Id is of datatype <code>nvarchar(128)</code>

Comment: One thing I'd be remiss to mention is that, in SQL Server, using a GUID is never a good thing to use as the clustered index of the table, regardless of how it's stored. By default, the primary key is also the clustered index, but that's a very poor choice if the PK is a GUID, as it leads to index fragmentation. Use an auto-identity `INT` or `BIGINT` as the clustered index, and then you can still have another column as the (non-clustered) primary key. There's lots of material on this, for example [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/clustered-or-nonclustered-index-on-a-random-guid/).

Comment: If this column never holds anything but a GUID, use the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type in the database, not `NVARCHAR(128)`. It saves considerably on storage (16 bytes vs. 64). If it might one day hold something that's not a GUID, `NVARCHAR(128)` might be acceptable (but probably still not as the clustered index, for the reasons mentioned above).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server then best practice for UniqueIndentifier/GUID PKs and Entity Framework would be:

1. Set up the database to assign a default on the PK column using (newsequentialid()). This will automatically generate new IDs that are better suited to clustered indexing. Do not use (newid()) or rely on `Guid.NewGuid()` in code to generate Guids. These play hell with indexes.
2. Set up EF primary keys with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` to inform EF that the keys will be handled by the database.
3. Utilize navigation properties for managing FK assignments, not FK properties. The reason for this is when creating parent-child hierarchies where the database is handling the PK, you won't know the parent ID until after SaveChanges and children should not have null-able FKs to their parent.

For example, given an Order with OrderLines, the OrderLine table would have a FK called OrderId back to the Order. You cannot:

```
var order = new Order 
{
  OrderNumber = orderVM.OrderNumber,
  // populate order details from view model...
}
context.Orders.Add(order);
foreach(orderLineVM in orderVM)
{
  var orderLine = new OrderLine
  {
     OrderId = order.OrderId // This will be 0 until after SaveChanges.
  }
  context.OrderLines.Add(orderLine);
}
```

Instead, you'll want Order to contain a mapped collection of OrderLines so that the insert operation would look more like:

```
var order = new Order 
{
  OrderNumber = orderVM.OrderNumber,
  // populate order details...
  OrderLines = orderVM.OrderLines.Select(ol => new OrderLine
  {
    // Populate order lines from view model.
  }).ToList(),
}
context.Orders.Add(order);
```

EF will then handle the FK association as the entities are saved.

Worst case, if you need to assign PKs client-side, read up on how newsequentialid() generates Guids in SQL Server and implement a helper method to create matching Guids. Note that if you use Oracle or other databases that support UUIDs etc. you should research how those are represented and indexed to use a format (Big vs. Little Endian) that complements indexing. In this you would also use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` to ensure EF/devs know that the PK is assigned by code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some attributes inside your Entity.

```
public class Item : Entity{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id{get;set;}
}
```